# Why does my app show a black screen on launch?

Tags: android

So I'm getting a black screen whenever I try to run my code through android studio

```
07-06 22:58:42.480 7969-7969/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-06 22:58:42.508 7969-7969/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
07-06 22:58:42.549 7969-7969/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.delma.ins-1/lib/arm64
07-06 22:58:42.551 7969-7969/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
07-06 22:58:42.557 7969-7979/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-06 22:58:42.557 7969-7979/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
07-06 22:58:42.618 7969-8006/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
07-06 22:58:42.624 7969-8006/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
07-06 22:58:42.628 7969-7969/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
07-06 22:58:42.636 7969-7969/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11020
07-06 22:58:42.636 7969-7969/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
07-06 22:58:42.642 7969-7969/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                       adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.delma.ins
07-06 22:58:42.642 7969-7969/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
07-06 22:58:42.651 7969-7969/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
07-06 22:58:42.672 7969-7969/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-06 22:58:42.682 7969-7969/? D/AccessibilityManager: current package=com.example.delma.ins, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
07-06 22:58:42.775 7969-7969/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
07-06 22:58:42.775 7969-7969/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
07-06 22:58:42.782 7969-7969/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
07-06 22:58:42.784 7969-7969/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
07-06 22:58:42.800 7969-7969/? W/ChimeraDebugLogger: Singleton logger instance not set.
07-06 22:58:42.805 7969-7969/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000070/n/arm64-v8a
07-06 22:58:42.818 7969-7969/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
07-06 22:58:42.871 7969-8043/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
07-06 22:58:42.876 7969-7969/? W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
07-06 22:58:43.049 7969-7969/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:452779 intent:Intent { flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.example.delma.ins/.LoginActivity }
07-06 22:58:43.509 7969-7969/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:453239 intent:Intent { flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.example.delma.ins/.MainActivity }
07-06 22:58:43.523 7969-8020/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
07-06 22:58:43.604 7969-7969/com.example.delma.ins W/ActionBarDrawerToggle: DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
07-06 22:58:43.609 7969-7969/com.example.delma.ins I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:453339 intent:Intent { flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.example.delma.ins/.LoginActivity }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have heavy work in the main thread, it will happen to ANR (android not responding), you should check your work, and a black screen is your application theme